# flutter pdf borderRadius doesn't apply to the boxShadow

Tags: css, flutter, pdf

I'm actually trying to make a health report using the flutter pdf library.
After adding a border-radius to my container, I realized that the shadow is still in form of a rectangle. Does box-shadow really work in this library?
I need your help guys. Thanks.

### here is my code :

```
pw.Container(
             margin: pw.EdgeInsets.symmetric(  vertical : format.height * 50 / designHeight),
             width: format.width * 0.4,
             height: format.height * 0.11,
             padding: pw.EdgeInsets.all(format.height * 60 / designHeight),
             decoration: pw.BoxDecoration(
             color: whiteColor,
             borderRadius: pw.BorderRadius.all(pw.Radius.circular(format.height * 130 /designHeight)),
                        boxShadow: [
                          pw.BoxShadow(
                            color: blur4Color,
                            spreadRadius:0.0,blurRadius: format.height * 22 / designHeight,offset: PdfPoint(0.0, format.height * 7 / designHeight),
                           ),
                        ],
                      ),
                      child: pw.Row(
                          mainAxisSize: pw.MainAxisSize.min,
                          crossAxisAlignment: pw.CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                          mainAxisAlignment: pw.MainAxisAlignment.center,
                          children: <pw.Widget>[
                            pw.Column(
                                crossAxisAlignment: pw.CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                mainAxisAlignment: pw.MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                children: <pw.Widget>[
                                  pw.Container(
                                      height: format.height * 63 / designHeight,
                                      child: pw.FittedBox(
                                          fit: pw.BoxFit.fitHeight,
                                          child: pw.Text(
                                            pdfData.podName == "null"
                                                ? "Boulanger"
                                                : pdfData.podName,
                                            style: pw.TextStyle(
                                              color: blackColor,
                                            ),
                                          ))),
                                  pw.SizedBox(
                                      height: format.height * 23.5 / designHeight),
                                  pw.Container(
                                    child: pw.Row(
                                      crossAxisAlignment:
                                          pw.CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                                      children: [
                                        pw.SvgImage(
                                          svg: podAdressIcon,
                                          width:
                                              (format.width * 43.9) / designWidth,
                                          height:
                                              (format.height * 58.6) / designHeight,
                                        ),
                                        pw.SizedBox(
                                            width:
                                                format.width * 16.9 / designWidth),
                                        pw.Container(
                                            height:
                                                format.height * 41 / designHeight,
                                            child: pw.FittedBox(
                                                fit: pw.BoxFit.fitHeight,
                                                child: pw.Text(
                                                  pdfData.addressLine1 ??
                                                      '' +
                                                          ', ' +
                                                          pdfData.zipCode +
                                                          ", " +
                                                          pdfData.city ??
                                                      "",
                                                  style: pw.TextStyle(
                                                    color: blurColor,
                                                  ),
                                                ))),
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ]),
                            pw.SizedBox(width: format.width * 62.9 / designWidth),
                            pw.Container(
                              width: format.width * 0.1,
                              height: format.width * 0.1,
                              decoration: pw.BoxDecoration(
                                borderRadius: pw.BorderRadius.all(
                                    pw.Radius.circular(format.width * 0.02)),
                                image: pw.DecorationImage(
                                    image: podImageSmall, fit: pw.BoxFit.fill),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ])))
```

[Expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KcCse.png)

[My result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pnl9n.png)

### Here is the design CSS :

```
.-Background {
  width: 1389.4px;
  height: 391.9px;
  margin: 50px 0 0;
  padding: 60.6px 59.3px 61.2px 70.2px;
  border-radius: 130px;
  box-shadow: 0 7px 22px 0 var(--black-5);
  background-color: #fff;
}
```